# Не могу добавить данные в базу данных с помощью Java

Tags: java, mysql

```
[![не добавилась колонка с названием str][1]][1]
public class T_shirt {
    private String name = "root";
    private String password = "root";
    private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/t_shirt?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Moscow&useSSL=false";

    private final String newField = "ALTER TABLE shirt ADD ? VARCHAR(40) after color";

    private Connection connection = null;
    private BufferedReader reader;

    T_shirt() {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = getConnection();
            addNewField();
        }catch (Exception exception){
            System.out.println(exception);
        }
    }

    public void addNewField() throws Exception{
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter string:");
        String str = reader.readLine();


        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(newField);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, str);
    }

    private Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuBmm.png
```

Comment: Запрос создали, теперь его надо выполнить preparedStatement.executeUpdate()

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko, не подскажите еще почему вот такая ошибка вылазит (java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''sdsd' VARCHAR(40)' at line 1) ?

Comment: Потому что имя поля не должно быть в кавычках, ни в одинарных, ни в двойных. Можно использовать "\` " для обрамления имени поля (таблицы, БД), если это имя совпадает с каким-либо зарезервированным словом. Но это не Ваш случай. В сообщении об ошибке аглицким по белому написано:  _near '**'sdsd'** VARCHAR(40)'_.

Comment: @IgorDyshlenko, так а как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ну, если при `preparedStatement.setString(1, str);` в SQL-выражение вставляется обрамленное кавычками значение, а в интерфейсе `Interface PreparedStatement` на первый взгляд подходящего метода для вставки имени поля не замечено (там кажется все методы заточены под запросы к данным, а не под изменение структуры таблиц), то всегда остается возможность самостоятельно сформировать строку запроса, подставив в нужное место нужное значение. Строки конкатенировать умеете? :)